# How to force Windows Comand Prompt to flush text output to a file line-by-line

Tags: file, cmd, stdout, flush

I'm trying to log every ping in my Windows CE5.0 machine Command Prompt using

```
> ping 192.168.1.1 -t -l 60000 >> ping.txt
```

The file starts with a single line of output and then only flushes after pressing 'ctrl+c'.

I was wondering if there was a way to force it to print in every new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know any direct way to do this.

But you could work around that by doing single ping requests in a (infinite) loop and write to the log file in the loop, like this:

```cmd
for /L %I in () do @(timeout 1 > nul & ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -l 60000 | find "TTL=" >> "ping.txt")
```

The `timeout 1` command establishes a one-second delay in every loop iteration in order to avoid heavy CPU load, `> nul` suppresses its console output.

The `find` command is used to filter for lines containing `TTL` from positive replies (like `Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=60000 time<1ms TTL=128`). If you want, you can change that to `findstr /B /C:"Reply from " /C:"Request " /C:"Ping request "`, for example, to capture positive replies as well as negative ones like `Request timed out.` or `Ping request could not find host ...`, or you can remove it completely (also the `|`) to write the whole `ping` response to the file, including header and footer.